# creating transparent checkout with Shopify API

Tags: node.js, graphql, payment-gateway, checkout, shopify-api

I'm trying to create a system similar to ABMEX or YAMP to perform transparent checkouts on Shopify, I can already create an application on the Shopify store, get the api key and the store link and within my application return the store's products with all your information, prices and quantities, now I want to create the checkout on yes so that when this product is purchased it will be through my checkout that I created but I'm lost in the documentation, can anyone help?